# How to display multiple graphs in real time with chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I make a chart that updates data in real time with Chartjs.
I want to display multiple graphs at the same time, but I can't update the data well.
I think it would be best if you could push the data of 'a' and 'b' respectively, as in the code below. I want to do something like `dataset.data [0] .push`, but that doesn't work (is it an object?). Are there any good breakthroughs?

```js
function onRefresh(chart) {
  for( var i=0; i<set.label.length; i++) {
  chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data.push({
      x: Date.now(),
      y: set.lebel[set.label.length-1]
    })
  });
 }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'a',
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: '...',
      borderColor: '...',
    }, {
      label: 'b',
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: '...',
      borderColor: '...',
}]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'realtime',
        realtime: {
          refresh: 1000,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                display: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                }
            }]
    },
    events: [],
    plugins: {
      streaming: {
        duration:  1000,
        delay: 1000,
    }
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datasets` is an array so it would be `dataset[0].data.push` rather than `dataset.data [0] .push`

But your `forEach` is looping through each dataset so you can just check if its the dataset you want to update:

```
function onRefresh(chart) {
  for( var i=0; i<set.label.length; i++) {
  chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    if (dataset.label === 'a') {
      // push the data to update a here
      dataset.data.push({
        x: Date.now(),
        y: set.lebel[set.label.length-1]
      })
    }
    // do the same for b
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
The if statement was a very effective way !!!
However, if this is the case, is there a difference in the time to enter a little data in a and b when looping?

Comment: if your data set isnt huge the time difference involved would be minimal

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so courteously ! You've been very helpful..